# Installing my Python script with pip

Tags: python, command, pip, command-line-interface

I packed my Python script in a `tgz` and installed it with `pip install file:///test.tgz`. No errors while installing, the files where placed inside `"/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/test"`.

The problem is that I can't call my script in the terminal, like I call ls or other software. I think It may have something to do with the `__init__.py`, but I'm clueless to what to do.

Comment: But what's your script looks like?

Comment: https://github.com/evertonstz/py-auto-brightness/blob/master/py-auto-brightness/py-auto-brightness.py